# how to handle rest api post data

Tags: mysql, api, laravel

Currently building out a RESTful web api and wondering the best way to handle POST data. Under normal circumstances i would not think twice about using multiple lookup tables. But in this case I do not want to take away from speed what so ever. What is the best way to handle incoming POST requests... Use multiple lookup tables?

```
Post Table:
id, user_id, game_id, job_id, etc
1, 20, 30, 45, 

Game Table:
id, name
1, game1
2, game2
3, game3 etc

Job Table:
id, name
1, Job1
2, Job2
3, Job3 etc
```

or do i just validate all incoming requests via the code and not accept any values that do not = Job1, Job2, Job3 etc?

Is there a best practice on how to handle all different types of incoming data?

Citti

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do in a simpler way? i find the question unclear

Comment: I am building an API. At the moment I seem to keep adding look up tables to handle storing of the data... The only problem with this is each lookup table keeps adding more time to the overall query when I go to retrieve this data via the API. I obviously want to return the "name" vs the ID ... I am wondering what is best practice when handling incoming POST requests... should I have users just input the Job ID or validate the string text that comes in and just store the plain text into the DB field eliminating the lookup dependencies...

Comment: or even keep the mysql layer as is with all the look up tables and add a caching layer in front of that?

Comment: a caching layer would be good, i think you can  add both lookups using name or ID with a caching layer that will improve the api (MUST BE DOCUMENTED) + make it fast and while you are using laravel caching would be easy using eloquent but i think its better to use lumen( consider it as a small laravel) its wayyyyyyy faster

Comment: and when caching, you can use a model observer to clear the cache that way things are more dynamic with less code

Comment: yea I am using Lumen. And yes the caching layer will help with speed when i get to that point. My only other question really would be how to handle those types of data that would use a lookup table. do i accept the ID or the string... Obviously either way would be documented. I was just thinking of using the actual strings and validate via lumen so that I wouldn't need so many look up tables... not sure if there is a best practice or not?

Comment: i think using the id is more common, lets suppose we have a page (get request ) where it shows all games, the user will see the names of games in a select box while the value will be the id so when posted ofc it would be the id that will be submitted ( same goes for other inputs) , excuse my english.

Comment: This is interesting, but Too Broad, Unclear, Primarily Opinion based